# Why request latency increases when adding more async requests, resulting in ridiculous load time?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, google-oauth

I have MVC app that is basically 1 main view and multiple partial views.
I have this tiny script on a min page that loads partials views asynchronously:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#bookmarks').load('Home/Bookmarks');
        $('#calendar').load('Home/Calendar');
        $('#gmail').load('Home/Gmail');
        $('#weather').load('Home/Weather');
        $("#news").load("Home/News");
    }
</script>
```

When I comment them all, I get this (very fast loading):

[image]

Now I uncomment just the "Bookmarks" request (just reads small JSON file from local drive), I get this (Bookmarks takes 9ms):

[image]

Now I uncomment the "Calendar" request (Google Calendar API), I get this (why Bookmarks latency jumps from 9ms to 1.04s if the requests are async?):

[image]

Now I uncomment the "Gmail" request (Google Gmail API), I get this (Bookmarks latency jumps again from  from 1.04s to 1.53s?):

[image]

Now I uncomment the rest ("Gmail", "Weather" and "News" requests), I get these insane increased latencies all over, the Bookmarks request takes now 5s to execute, instead of 9ms - why?):

[image]

You can see the increase in latency for each operation - it looks like these ajax requests are not asynchronous at all :( How is that possible, when AJAX is supposed to be async by default?

I am sure I am missing something here, may jQuery load function is not async, but it's on javascript size, and the delay is on server-side. I am now confused.

Update: obviously jQuery call are async, all load functions are executed at the same time. It's easy. The problem is on the server side. After having dome some tests, it's clear that **IIS executes these request synchronously, sequentially** one after another in the order it received them from the browser. I have done some additional reading on IIS, and by default IIS apppool has only 1 worker process that is being used, that can fire multiple threads for processing all these requests. **But for some reason**, the requests **are being processed sequentially and not in parallel**. I haven't found yet why (if a AppPool worker process can start many threads for simultaneous processing) the requests are still executed sequentially, and  how to make these requests to be processed in parallel, and if it's even possible. If someone has any idea how to make thing work properly I would really like to hear. Thanks.

**Update** After some more reading, found that requests are processed sequentially if Session is enabled. The session object is a single threaded object. The session object cannot be shared by two threads simultaneously. Hence when there are two requests for the same session one is queued while the session object is in use by the other. This sucks :( Any suggestions, IIS experts? :)

**Solved**
Yes, Session State was the problem! I disabled session state in web.config  and removed one line that used Session object to avoid runtime error. Now everything works perfect. The true problem was indeed - that Session state is bound to a single thread, therefore on the server side my app behaved like an old STA fart :)

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

**Concurrent Requests and Session State**

Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each separate session is granted concurrently. However, **if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished.** (The second session can also get access if the exclusive lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the lock time-out.) If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data. However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After some more reading, found that requests are processed
>   sequentially if Session is enabled. The session object is a single
>   threaded object. The session object cannot be shared by two threads
>   simultaneously. Hence when there are two requests for the same session
>   one is queued while the session object is in use by the other. This
>   sucks :( Any suggestions, IIS experts? :)

Don't use `Session`. I rarely find cases that justify use of `Session`, and it's often easy to find storage alternatives that don't have the scalability limitations that you run into with it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I disabled session state in web.config <sessionState mode="Off"></sessionState> and removed that one line that used Session object to avoid runtime error. Now everything works perfect. The true problem was indeed - that Session state is bound to a single thread, therefore on the server side my app behaved like an old STA fart :) Thanks man!